# i want to count 2 cells as 1 if either of these 2 cells contain value or number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my question is that that is you can see in the pic B1andC1 Cells are merged showing the date 1st december along with the rest of the row
in B2 showing D and C2 showing P below that are the values of these specific criterias.

[image]

now what i need is in T3 that if on Dec,1 if B3 and C3 have value or numbers then show me in T3 "1" if either of B3 or C3 have value or number also show me "1" but if either of these 2 Cells don't have value or number then don't count these 2 cells

like on Dec,5 Both D and P don't have number or value so i want it to skip it if either of these cells would have value then it should be count

like it shown in the 2nd pick the count is showing 13 but the actual working days are 7 days

please if someone can help in for this i've been searching for this from like a month

[image]

i tried the if formula , count formul but i m not that good in formulas

Answer (score 0):

### Conditionally Count Groups of Consecutive Cells in a Row

**Spill Down**

```
=LET(data,B3:S12,cells,2,
    s,cells*(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/cells)-1)+1,
BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,
    REDUCE(,s,LAMBDA(rr,c,
        rr+((SUM(LEN(INDEX(r,,SEQUENCE(cells,,c)))))>0))))))
```

[image]

**Copy Down**

```
=LET(data,B3:S3,cells,2,
REDUCE(,cells*(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/cells)-1)+1,LAMBDA(rr,c,
    rr+((SUM(LEN(INDEX(data,,SEQUENCE(cells,,c)))))>0))))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help it works perfectly in excel but i want to apply it in google sheets as well there it showing me error

Error
Function SEQUENCE parameter 2 value is 0. It should be greater than or equal to 1.